# Unexpected non-void return value in void function - Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, return, closures, void

Not letting me return the username value because its in a closure. May someone please explain to me how to use the @escaping and void closure

Error: Unexpected non-void return value in void function

```
func grabUsername () -> String {
    let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    let database = Firestore.firestore().collection("Users").document(uid!)
    database.getDocument { (docSnapshot, error) in
           guard let docSnapshot = docSnapshot, docSnapshot.exists else {return}
           let mydata = docSnapshot.data()
           let username = mydata!["Username"] as? String ?? ""
           return username
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `getDocument` is asynchronous method with callback closure having no return, so you cannot return from it, instead you have to apply results somewhere, eg. in property

So the solution can be as follow

```
var username: String = ""

// ... other your code

func grabUsername () { // << async, no immediate return
    let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    let database = Firestore.firestore().collection("Users").document(uid!)
    database.getDocument { (docSnapshot, error) in
           guard let docSnapshot = docSnapshot, docSnapshot.exists else {return}
           let mydata = docSnapshot.data()
           let username = mydata!["Username"] as? String ?? ""

           DispatchQueue.main.async {
              self.username = username // << store result
           }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of returning a String value, making it a closure will be a better approach, as `database.getDocument` is returning an error also in a closure.

So make your function as a closure.

like this.

```
    func grabUsername (completion: @escaping (Error?, String?) -> Void) {
    let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    let database = Firestore.firestore().collection("Users").document(uid!)
    database.getDocument { (docSnapshot, error) in
        if error != nil {  completion(error.localizedDescription!, nil) } else {  guard let docSnapshot = docSnapshot, docSnapshot.exists else {return}
            let mydata = docSnapshot.data()
            let username = mydata!["Username"] as? String ?? ""
            completion(nil, username)
        }
    }
}
```